# background-color no funciona en algunos navegadores móviles

Tags: html, css

Tengo un error muy extraño. Es sobre la propiedad `background-color` de **CSS**.

Esta propiedad funciona bien en navegadores de escritorio y en la mayoría de navegadores móviles, pero en algunos navegadores móviles no aplica el color de fondo.

¿Esto a que se deberá? ¿A alguien le ha pasado esto?

Si me pudiera orientar, por favor, dejo mi código:

```html
<div class="cuadro">
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
</div>
```

El código **CSS** es el siguiente donde le aplico un color blanco de fondo, pero como lo menciono es algo muy extraño, ya que solo en algunos navegadores móviles no aplica el color y este se pone trasparente dejando ver los elementos que se encuentra debajo de él.

> **Nota:** el `background-color` solo en algunos navegadores móviles no se aplica de tal manera que se me hace muy extraño. No tengo mucha experiencia en **CSS.**
>
> Espero me orienten.

Fragmento de código **CSS:**

```css
.cuadro {
    position: fixed;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #ffff;
    border: 1px #666 solid;
    border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 100%;
    top: 60px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 4px #5b5858;
    transition: margin-left 1s;
}
```

Comment: Prueba poniéndole `background` en vez de `background-color`, no suele pasar con navegadores móviles, pero puede ser el caché, hay que refrescarlo también, fuera de eso no le encuentro otra solución a esto. Además esa propiedad `transition` debe tener los _[Prefijos](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)_

Comment: Es extraño que esto ocurra. Prueba a poner el color como "#fff" o "#ffffff".

Comment: En background-color prueba con #fff o #ffffff

Comment: Esto resolvió el problema muchas gracias